# Enviar datos Checkbox método GET

Tags: php

Buen día, el inconveniente es el siguiente, tengo un formulario PHP llamado "Liquidacion.PHP"allí muestro una tabla con registros y para todos los registros tengo un checkbox, mediante URL envío datos a un formulario llamado "funciones.php", puedo recibir mediante GET los datos enviados en la URL, pero no he podido captrar en funciones los registros del Checkbox. A continuación relaciono el código de "Liquidación.php"

```html
<a href = "funciones/funciones.php?Ano=<?php echo $Ano ?>&Mes=<?php echo $Mes ?> &periodo=<?php echo $periodo ?> &Concepto=<?php echo $Concepto ?> &&Delete=TbLiquidacion"onclick="return validarC()"><button type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-lg" name="btn-altas" id="btn-altas"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Liquidar...</button></a>

   ?>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name "IDNov[]" value="<?php echo$fila[12] ?>" checked></td >
   <?php
```

el código de "funciones.php" es el siguiente:

```html
 $Mes=$_GET['Mes'];
 $Ano=$_GET['Ano'];
 $periodo=$_GET['periodo'];
 $Concepto=$_GET['Concepto'];
 $IdNov=$_GET['IDNov'];
    if(@$_GET['btn-altas']))
  // if (isset($_GET['IDNov']))
    {
     echo "Entramos";
  foreach($_GET['IDNov'] as $IDNov)
  {
   echo $IDNov;
  }
  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

La solucion:

1) Tienes un error en la sintaxis para la etiqueta del input checkbox, el atributo no es el correcto.

2) Para pasar los datos del formulario se necesita un input submit.

Cambiar:

```
<input type="checkbox" name "IDNov[]" value="<?php echo$fila[12] ?>" checked>
```

Por este:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IDNov" value="<?php echo$fila[12] ?>" checked>
```

Anexo un ejemplo del funcionamiento del input checkbox

Archivo Liquidacion.php

```
<form action="funciones.php" method="GET">
    <input type="checkbox" name="IDNov" value="valor1" checked>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Archivo funciones.php

```
<?php
$IdNov=$_GET['IDNov'];
echo $IdNov;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar un dato de un checkbox hacia una base de datos debes usar el método $_POST, y lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="funciones.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="IDNov[]">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Tienes que tener un archivo php que sea el "manejador" de tu formulario hacia donde lo quieres enviar, comúnmente a una base de datos. Suponiendo es tu caso lo realizas mediante el método $_POST y se incluye en la casilla de "action".

Puedes usar la casilla de name para insertar el nombre que adquirirá tu lista de opciones, o como se le conoce: un array, como en el ejemplo.

Después en tu archivo manejador hacia la base de datos, le indicas que es un checkbox, y lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$IDNov = $_POST['valor1'];
$b = implode($IDNov);
```

De esta manera php convierte o une elementos de un array en un string y en tu base de datos te aparecera en una línea de texto, que en tu caso viene siendo "valor1".

Como no mostraste tu archivo que envía los datos te lo hago saber.

En cuanto al "checked" no sé porque esta ahí pues un usuario debería de seleccionar una casilla, tal vez no sea tu caso. Gracias.